# Golang net/smtp send email over tls

Tags: email, ssl, go

The [wiki example](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SendingMail) shows an example of sending mail on port 25, but Google SMTP Server requires tls over port 465. Can someone show an example using tls?

Comment: Have you tried [StartTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client.StartTLS)?

Comment: here it is, tls [gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisgillis/10888032) on github

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [`SendMail`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail) function. From the docs:

> SendMail connects to the server at addr, switches to TLS if possible, authenticates with the optional mechanism a if possible, and then sends an email from address from, to addresses to, with message msg. The addr must include a port, as in "mail.example.com:smtp".

Comment: Yes I figured out that adding the tls port number works, but SendMail has a function "StartTLS" which I'm guessing it calls on its own (switches to TLS if possible)?